# Algorithm exercise

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on this algorithm exercise but I don't understand completely the formulation. Here is the exercise:

> Given a string str and array of pairs that indicates which indices in
>   the string can be swapped, return the lexicographically largest string
>   that results from doing the allowed swaps. You can swap indices any
>   number of times.
>
> Example
>
> For str = "abdc" and pairs = [[1, 4], [3, 4]], the output should be
>   swapLexOrder(str, pairs) = "dbca".
>
> By swapping the given indices, you get the strings: "cbda", "cbad",
>   "dbac", "dbca". The lexicographically largest string in this list is
>   "dbca".
>
> Input/Output
>
> [execution time limit] 4 seconds (js)
>
> [input] string str
>
> A string consisting only of lowercase English letters.
>
> Guaranteed constraints: 1 ≤ str.length ≤ 104.
>
> [input] array.array.integer pairs
>
> An array containing pairs of indices that can be swapped in str
>   (1-based). This means that for each pairs[i], you can swap elements in
>   str that have the indices pairs[i][0] and pairs[i][1].
>
> Guaranteed constraints: 0 ≤ pairs.length ≤ 5000, pairs[i].length = 2.
>
> [output] string

My question is, why "abcd" is not a posible answer (just swapping index 3 and 4 on the original string "abdc")? The example says

> By swapping the given indices, you get the strings: "cbda", "cbad",
>   "dbac", "dbca". The lexicographically largest string in this list is
>   "dbca"

I understand that even if "abcd" is a possible answer "dbca" is lexicographically largest so the answer is the same. But if I don't understand why "abcd" is not a possible answer I think I'm misunderstanding the task

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the question correctly, and their description is broken.  Both `"abcd"` and `"abdc"` are on the list of possible strings that you can produce, and yet are not in their list.